# Baqend is not working with emulator or real device using ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, baqend

I'm developing an app using Baqend and ionic. When I run `ionic serve` the app runs fine in the browser and it is able to call Baqend. However, when I run `ionic cordova emulate ios` suddenly Baqend is not working in the Xcode emulator and it does not produce any errors in the console even with adding the `--consolelog` parameter.

I also tried:

1. Opening the project inside of Xcode and running it from there but same result.
2. Running the ionic/Baqend starter (https://github.com/baqend/ionic1-starter) and same result.

How can I debug this issue?

**Update:** I just tested it with Android using `ionic cordova emulate android` and it worked fine. So it seems that the issue only exist with ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding `<allow-navigation href="https://*.app.baqend.com/*" />` in config.xml file.